# React-native axios method POST response.data null

Tags: post, mobile, react-native, axios

I use React-native for my school project and axios to take data.
here is my function :

```
    login(username, password){

    axios({
        method : 'post',
        url : 'http://xxxx.xxxx.com/UserRestController.php',
        data : {
            accountId : 2
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log('data', response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

when I try to show response, this is always null. 
Like this

```
      data Object {
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
    "data": "{\"accountId\":2}",
    "headers": Object {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    },
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "post",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": Object {
      "0": [Function transformRequest],
    },
    "transformResponse": Object {
      "0": [Function transformResponse],
    },
    "url": "http://ariary.vola.mg/UserRestController.php",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  },
  "data": "",
  "headers": Object {
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Mon, 31 Jul 2017 13:29:28 GMT",
    "server": "nginx",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x-powered-by": "EasyEngine 3.7.4",
  },
  "request": XMLHttpRequest {
    "DONE": 4,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
```

I use axios.GET in another function, and it works great. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: thanks, how can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the response to json before accessing it's data like this:

```
axios({
    method : 'post',
    url : 'http://xxxx.xxxx.com/UserRestController.php',
    data : {
        accountId : 2
    }
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then(function (response) {
console.log('data', response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but wher I tried as you say I have this error. 
   
         [TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'res.json()')]

Answer (score 0):

After some test, my problem is not the response but my data. This is always null. the accountId is undefined in my server. But I don't know why?

Comment: Could be a few options: add correct headers like 'accept: application/json'. Or parse the json in the data you're sending to a string with JSON.stringify()